# OpenCV casting of vector<Point>.data to Point* resulting in an unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, casting, point

In a OpenCV C++ program I have a function with this body.

```
  for (int ii=0; ii< static_cast<int>(parks.size()); ii++)
  {
     PolygonVertices temp = parks.at(ii).getPoly();
     const Point *pts = (const cv::Point*) Mat(parks.at(ii).getPoly()).data;
     int npts = Mat(parks.at(ii).getPoly()).rows;
     for (int jj=0; jj<npts; jj++)
     {
         cout<<"----"<<jj<<"----"<<endl;
         cout<<"x: "<<pts[jj].x<<", y: "<<pts[jj].y<<endl;
         cout<<"x: "<<temp[jj].x<<", y: "<<temp[jj].y<<endl;
         cout<<"--------"<<endl;
     }
  }
}
```

`Polygonvertices` is a type defined as `typedef std::vector<cv::Point>` and the method `getPoly()` returns such a structure.

I am casting the `Polygonvertices` (which is a vector of `Point`) data to a pointer of `Point` type.

The points are selected with the mouse.

The problem is that printing the `x` and `y` coordinates of both the element of the pointer and the original element, for the first element (index 0) data coming from the pointer are shifted.

For example this is the output:

```
----0----
x: -1871319456, y: 21975
x: 286, y: 304
--------
----1----
x: 325, y: 218
x: 325, y: 218
--------
----2----
x: 375, y: 280
x: 375, y: 280
```

As you can see the first element is totally shifted away?

What is happening? Is the casting wrong?

This is happening  using OpenCV4 under Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Beware that `temp` is a copy, and a list of vertices is generally not something you want to be copying much.

Comment: `temp` was just to check if the input data are correct. It will not be modified. It will be removed after the problem will be solved.

Comment: Is `.data` a data member or a member function? `(const cv::Point*)` is very suspicious and you might be casting a function pointer to a data pointer. Avoid c style casts, they are too strong and often hide errors.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was worng about data: let me check maybe I confused dat() from vector with data of Mat opencv object.

Comment: I'm not an expert with OpenCV but it seems like the pointer returned by `Mat::data` will be invalidated if the associated `Mat` object is destroyed. Since you are making a temporary `Mat` it will be destroyed at the end of the expression, making the obtained pointer unusable.

Comment: but changing `parks.at(ii).getPoly().data()` will not create any new vector so the pointer, at least inside the function should be always valid. And the error remains.

Comment: Why do you even need a `Mat`? Simple `&temp[0]` will give you what you need (pointer to the first `cv::Point` in the vector).

Comment: The line you describe doesn't exist in the code you've shown. I'm talking about `Mat(parks.at(ii).getPoly()).data`. And if we assume the line you describe did exist, it would depend on what `getPoly()` returns. If it returns a value, then you would still be getting `data()` from a temporary. If it returns a reference, it might work.

Comment: @DanMašek's solutions worked and it is very smart. I have one question still though: why does `Point *pts = &temp[0];` while `Point *pts = &( (parks.at(ii).getPoly())[0]);` does not? Is it because the value returned is not stored anywher?

Comment: In the second case you're taking a pointer to the internal members of a temporary, which ceases to exist after that statement is executed (the memory pointed to may hold anything, but it's incorrect to access it).

Comment: So basically I was seeing some valid data because not all the memory where the temporary was stored has been overwritten but only part of it. Right?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Exactly.